# SolrCloud 5 and Zookeeper config upload

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I'm in the middle of configuring SolrCloud with Zookeeper but I struggle to load the config on ZK.

Here my steps:

1. Configure an ensemble of 3 ZK, I see 1 leader and 2 follower
2. Configure a small cluster of 2 of SolrCloud that is started as followed
   `/bin/solr start -c -z <ip1>:2181,<ip2>:2181,<ip3>:2181  -noprompt`
3. Then I tried to load the config on ZK using zkCli.sh:
   `./bin/zkCli.sh -zkhost <ip1>:2181,<ip2>:2181,<ip3>:2181 -cmd upconfig -confname config1  -confdir /folder/with/schema.xml` (it come from solr standalone)
4. Create Solr collection using API
   `http://<solr_ip>:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=collection_test&numShards=2&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=2`
5. Link the config to the collection using again zkCli.sh
   `./bin/zkCli.sh -zkhost 127.0.0.1:2181 -cmd linkconfig -collection collection_test -confname config1`

At this point I should see the config loaded but nothing happens.

Answer (score 6):

I used below steps to configure SolrCloud in my VM.

SolrCloud Setup Instructions

1. Infrastructure

   ```
   a.  Unix Boxes 3
   b.  ELB 1
   c.  create cnames for the unix boxes as cl-solr1, cl-solr2, cl-solr3
   ```
2. Installations

   ```
   a.  Install zookeeper-3.4.6 (zookeeper-3.4.6.tar.gz)
   b.  solr-5.2.1 (solr-5.2.1.tgz)
   c.  OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.7.0_79
   ```
3. Setup

   ```
   a.  Set JAVA_HOME
   b.  In cl-solr1,cl-solr2,cl-solr3 create zoo.cfg file with below content at /opt/myname/zookeeper-3.4.6/conf
           tickTime=2000
           dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/data
           clientPort=2181
           initLimit=5
           syncLimit=2
           server.1=cl-solr1:2888:3888
           server.2=cl-solr2:2888:3888
           server.3=cl-solr3:2888:3888
   ```

   c.  Create myid file for each zookeeper server cl-solr1, cl-solr2 & cl-solr3 using below command
       $mkdir -p /var/lib/zookeeper/data/
       $echo 1 > /var/lib/zookeeper/data/myid   --1 for cl-solr1 and 2 for cl-solr2 ..
4. Start the zookeeper

   ```
   a.  /opt/myname/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkServer.sh start
   b.  /opt/myname/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkServer.sh status
   c.  Status check in detail via
       echo stat | nc cl-solr1 2181
   ```
5. Start the SOLR

   ```
   a.  cl-solr1$ /opt/myname/solr-5.2.1/bin/solr start -c -z cl-solr1:2181,cl-solr2:2181,cl-solr3:2181 -h cl-solr1
   b.  cl-solr2$ /opt/myname/solr-5.2.1/bin/solr start start -c -z cl-solr1:2181,cl-solr2:2181,cl-solr3:2181 -h cl-solr2
   c.  cl-solr3$ /opt/myname/solr-5.2.1/bin/solr start -c -z cl-solr1:2181,cl-solr2:2181,cl-solr3:2181 -h cl-solr3
   ```
6. Create a new Collection

   ```
   a.  From one of the nodes (cl-solr1) fire below commands
       i.  mkdir -p /opt/myname/solr-5.2.1/server/solr/pats/conf
       ii. Copy conf folder from current system
       iii.    /opt/myname/solr-5.2.1/bin/solr create -c my_colln_name -d /opt/myname/solr-5.2.1/server/solr/pats/conf -n myname_cfg -shards 2 -replicationFactor 2
   ```

Comment: Thank you, I made a mistake on the last line trying to load on ZK and the link but didn't work, now is fine.

Comment: Good, please mark the question as closed if this works for you