# Solr 5.2.1 installation on Hadoop 2.6.0 multi node setup

Tags: hadoop, solr, solr5

Looking for some help on installing Solr on an existing hadoop 3 node cluster.
I am trying to install solr 5.2.1 on hadoop 2.6.0.

Checked few blogs but everyone is giving configuration of solr 4.10.3 on single node.

**Need any document or steps which give installation steps for solr 5.2.1 on multinode hadoop cluter using YARN.**

Regards,
Ankit Gupta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, this will help you or not, but please have a cross check at [SolrCloud 5 and Zookeeper config upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790202/solrcloud-5-and-zookeeper-config-upload/31795397#31795397)

Certain Commands which can be used for you are as below.

1. Create a conf directory with all the conf files
2. Run this from one of the node 
   /opt/myname/solr-5.2.1/bin/solr create -c my_collection -d /opt/myname/solr-5.2.1/server/solr/myconf/conf -n my_colln_cfg -shards 2 -replicationFactor 2

Some other helpful links are as below
http://cl-solr2:8080/solr/admin/collections?action=ADDREPLICA&name=myname_all&collection=myname_all&node=cl-solr1:8080_solr&shard=shard1_0
http://cl-solr2:8080/solr/admin/collections?action=SPLITSHARD&name=myname_all&collection=myname_all&shard=shard1
http://cl-solr1:8080/solr/admin/collections?action=DELETESHARD&collection=myname_all&shard=shard1_0
http://cl-solr1:8080/solr/admin/collections?action=RELOAD&name=myname_all
http://cl-solr1:8080/solr/admin/collections?action=DELETEREPLICA&collection=myname_all&shard=shard1&replica=core_node3
http://cl-solr1:8080/solr/admin/collections?action=DELETE&name=myname_all

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The link provided helped me getting started solr in local mode. I want to bring it up in cluster mode. I have a 3 node hadoop cluster and have solr on all 3 machine.

Comment: Link provided by me should bring up the instance in cluster node. Make sure you passed the zooker information during start command. Below command can be used to validate the same. /opt/solr-5.2.1/bin/solr status

Comment: When i see the webUI solr is started on each nodes ip address at 8983 port

When executed 

solr status
got result

 **solr status**

Found 1 Solr nodes:

Solr process 18321 running on port 8983
{
  "solr_home":"/usr/local/solr/server/solr/",
  "version":"5.2.1 1684708 - shalin - 2015-06-10 23:20:13",
  "startTime":"2015-08-11T05:53:10.22Z",
  "uptime":"0 days, 0 hours, 1 minutes, 37 seconds",
  "memory":"85.2 MB (%17.4) of 490.7 MB",
  "cloud":{
    "ZooKeeper":"hdmaster:2181,hdslave1:2181,hdslave2:2181",
    "liveNodes":"3",
    "collections":"0"}}

confirm if output is correct

Comment: Yes out put state liveNodes 3, which means you are in a cluser mode. Please close the thread if this helps.

Comment: Just like HBASE or SPARK do we have a WebURL to see all nodes in one WebUI for Solr

Comment: Yes, you can see them when you have a collection created which is distributed across the nodes. Say, create a collection with 2 shards and 2 replicas. Then you can see them distributed over the 3 nodes and a graphical view can be found at http://cl-solr1:8983/solr/#/~cloud

Comment: Can you please help me with some link or document which shares example on how create collections and shards along with sample examples?